# How to read data from Bluetooth by realtime?

Tags: android

Hi:
  I'm developing a android program to read data from a remote device by bluetooth. Now, the remote device sends 5 bytes every second, but when I read the InputStream on Android, I received the 2,1,2,3... bytes. The question is that I want to receive these data by realtime, and what should I do?
  By the way, my program is based on the BluetoohChat which provided by Android.
  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a `Thread` or `AsyncTask` which handles reading from the Bluetooth socket. That thread/task might for example loop four times per second, looking for data from Bluetooth. Once it gets enough data to perform an action, that thread could execute another function which processes the data.